# Filtering row start given a specific result

Tags: sql, ssms

I want to create a survival analysis datatable. However, Im having a small problem. Look at the image to see the output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL27W.png)

What I need is my query to start from the min(Fechacarga) where Estado = S. Also, this variable will, at some point, start to generate N's and I want to keep those and there will be more than just one client.

Basically, I want to keep all the Ns before the Ss, but delete all the rows that have Ns before Ss (for each client).

This is my actual code:

```
select Codigo_Cliente,
        Es_Cliente Estado,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Codigo_Cliente order by Fechacarga) as Mes,
        FechaCarga
from Clientes_MAC
where FechaCarga in (SELECT   MAX(fecha)
FROM (
    select DISTINCT(FECHACARGA) as fecha
    FROM CLIENTES_MAC   
) fec           
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha), YEAR(fecha)
)
and Codigo_Cliente = 363193
```

Comment: Hi Marcos,  can you clarify this : " Basically, I want to keep all the Ns before the Ss, but delete all the rows that have Ns before Ss (for each client).". Please if you can post the data it would be easier for us to work, instead try to reconstruct  it from an image. Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will get a much better response if you paste your actual data rather than a picture of the data. As it stands, anyone wanting to help will probably have to code your picture back into text to test it out. Help us to help you!